# Equals method on list of lists

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

Let this be a definition of a matrix:

```
private List<<List<Object>> lines;

public boolean equals(Object o){
      if(this==o)
         return true;
      if((o==null) || (this.getClass()!=o.getClass()))
         return false;
      Matrix m = (Matrix) o;
      return ????;
}
```

how can I compare all those lines and columns.

Can I just use

```
return this.lines.equals(o.getLines());
```

??

Thanks

Comment: The `Object` class in Java doesn't have a `getLines()` method, so, no.

Comment: What is the purpose of casting o to a matrix?

Comment: You can't just put that, since it's an incorrect statement, however the idea is sound if you use the correct arguments.

Comment: Yes, you can use `return this.lines.equals(m.getLines())`, but you have to 1) make sure that objects put in those list have properly defined `equals` as well, and 2) you handle the case when `this.lines` is null (it shouldn't throw an NPE, so that your `equals` is symmetric).

Answer (score 2):

More or less, though that exact code doesn't quite work.

From the `List.equals` javadoc:

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).)

You can indeed use this method to determine equality, but you need to cast `o` first. This is a safe cast because you already checked the class (though you might consider using `instanceof Matrix` instead).

```
return this.lines.equals(((Matrix)o).getLines());
```

Comment: `instanceof` doesn't catch subtypes, i.e. if `o` is an instance of a subtype of `Matrix` it will still evaluate to `true`. `this.getClass() != o.getClass()` is more specific, in that it will evaluate `true` unless both are the same identical class.

Comment: By design, an object should be equal if its logically sound for them to be so. If I have a 4x4 `Rectangle`, and I want to test equality to a 4x4 `Square`, I should get `true`. I suppose this might depend on the circumstances of the class's purpose, though.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The circumstances are key. I was just throwing light on the idea that `instanceof` _is different than_ the OP's `Class != Class`. Your suggestion that OP "might consider using" `instanceof` is correct. OP (and anyone else reading) should understand (at least some of) the differences between the two incantations in order to correctly consider using one instead of the other.

Comment: You're right, I should have clarified _why_ he should consider its use.